# oracle rman duplicate database

Tags: oracle, database-backups, rman

I'm trying to duplicate from active database. I have configured everything according to oracle docs. still in the middle of the process I get the error

```
RMAN-06025: no backup of archived log for thread 1 with sequence 58 and starting SCN of 2001221 found to restore
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.
ps: this is my rman configuration on the source database:

```
RMAN configuration parameters for database with db_unique_name XE are:
CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF;
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/backup/ora_df%t_s%s_s%p';
CONFIGURE MAXSETSIZE TO UNLIMITED; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION FOR DATABASE OFF; # default
CONFIGURE ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM 'AES128'; # default
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'BASIC' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD TRUE ; # default
CONFIGURE ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY TO NONE; # default
CONFIGURE SNAPSHOT CONTROLFILE NAME TO '/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/dbs/snapcf_XE.f'; # default
```

Comment: Provide the command that you have used to duplicate the database.

Comment: thank you for your comment. it's 'duplicate target database to xe - from active database - nofilenamecheck"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching to backup based duplication. at fist I got the same error, following instructions in here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2

I did a point in time duplicate and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used Oracle 12c. For copying 1 db to another say from some test stage to own local machine and own local DB use the bundled app **SQL Developer** that comes with the installation. In the menu choose tools -> database copy.

The rest is quite self explanatory. You choose source and target DB and choose to copy only the objects or a whole schema. There might some permission involved here also depending on roles and permissions.